# Assimp doens't return texture data

Tags: c++, assimp

Im using assimp to load 3D models.
My models have embedded textures ("I guess"). But I have two problems:

1. I can't find a way to actually get the texture file path ...
2. The pcData doensn't seems to be anything.

I can't not even print the width or height of the texture.

printing the `texturefile` I get that usual format `*0 *1` and so On.

But when I try to print the `scene->mTextures[atoi(texturefile.C_Str())]->mFileName` I get nothing...same thing with texture pcData.

here's the code:

```
uint32_t textureCount = scene->mMaterials[i]->GetTextureCount(aiTextureType_DIFFUSE);

for (uint32_t c = 0; c < textureCount ; c++) {
    scene->mMaterials[i]->GetTexture(aiTextureType_DIFFUSE, c, &texturefile);
    std::cout << "\n textureFile : " << texturefile.C_Str() << std::endl;
    std::cout <<"\nTextura : "<< scene->mTextures[atoi(texturefile.C_Str())]<<std::endl;
    aiTexture *texture = scene->mTextures[atoi(texturefile.C_Str())];

    int w = texture->mWidth;
    int h = texture->mHeight;

    if (texture == NULL) {
        std::cout << "\n TextureNull\n";
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "\n textureNotNull\n";
    }

    uint32_t *data = reinterpret_cast<uint32_t* >(texture->pcData);
    createTextureImage(data, w, h, materials[i].texturesImages[c]);

    //createTextureImageView(materials[i].texturesImagesViews[c], materials[i].texturesImages[c]);
    //createTextureSampler(materials[i].texturesSamplers[c]);

    //  void createTextureImage(uint32_t* pixels,int texWidth,int texHeight,VkImage textureImage) {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

When working with the lastest master the following code shall work for you:

```
aiMaterial material = scene->mMaterials[index];
aiString texture_file;
material->Get(AI_MATKEY_TEXTURE(aiTextureType_DIFFUSE, 0), texture_file);
if(auto texture = scene->GetEmbeddedTexture(texture_file.C_Str())) {
   //returned pointer is not null, read texture from memory
} else {
   //regular file, check if it exists and read it
}
```

In older versions you have to look for a special token:

```
aiMaterial material = scene->mMaterials[index];
aiString texture_file;
material->Get(AI_MATKEY_TEXTURE(aiTextureType_DIFFUSE, 0), texture_file);
if('*' == texture_file.data[0]) {
  //embedded texture, get index from string and access scene->mTextures
} else {
  //regular file, check if it exists and read it
}
```

Hope that helps to understand the concept.

Comment: Helpful to keep in mind, `texture->mHeight` can be zero, in this case `texture->pcData` is not RGB values but compressed JPEG/PNG etc. data. You need a decoder to decode such data and I recommend `stb_image.h` from nothings.