# How could i convert texture from Assimp to UTexture2D from Unreal engine

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4, texture2d, assimp

I'm working on load FBX/Obj file to UE4 with Assimp library， it's works good for Android, IOS and Windows for now. The problems is i need to import the texture sperate every time i load the 3D Mesh, so i hope i can read the texture directly with Assimp from the fbx file(there is kind of similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56820244/assimp-doenst-return-texture-data)):

actually i can get the aiTexture from Assimp, inside there is data of the texture called  pcData, inside pcData, there are actully have "R,G,B,A", so i think with those info, i can actually create a Texture2D, and copy "R,G,B,A" from pcData, but due to my poor C++, i don't really know how to coding this part, is there anyone can help me with that? Thanks inadvance.

Comment: similar question here, with a solution for blueprint, mayb it could help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63934818/ue4-assimp-issues-loading-mtl-texture-at-runtime

Comment: Thanks for your information, it's similar but not exactly same question, the texture i get from FBX is not the really path so i can't use the node "import File as UTexture2D", i can actually get the data of texture, but don't know how to transfer to some like "TArray<uInt8>" , that's the problem is